# MySQL and presorting tables

Tags: mysql, optimization, indexing

I have a MySQL database on my server with one table with a primary index and fulltext indexing on all other columns. Typically I execute a SELECT statement like:

`SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE MATCH(myInfo) AGAINST ('stuff') ORDER BY id LIMIT 30`

This is working fine, however it is slow - the `ORDER BY id` clause is slowing things down considerably, particularly when there are a lot of hits as often happens. For example, without the clause searches take ~0.001 seconds and with the clause 0.6 seconds (but yields the ideal results).

1. Is it possible to presort my table so that I don't ever need the `ORDER BY` operator? The table is static - the data will only ever be read. After all, having to sort 5000 hits only to return (the top) 30 seems a waste when this can be easily decided in the advance.
2. If not, what can I do about this?

PS - `MATCH` seems to jumble things up, whereas `LIKE` although slow does not and so does not need `ORDER BY`.

%%
Edit #1, with output of `EXPLAIN SELECT` on phpMyAdmin

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    Extra

1   SIMPLE  myTable fulltext    full_index  full_index  0       1   Using where
```

Edit #2, better EXPLAIN

indicates time is spent sorting the results.

Status                          Time

starting                    0.000016

checking query cache for query  0.000048

Opening tables                  0.000012

System lock                 0.000007

Table lock                  0.000024

init                            0.000026

optimizing                  0.000010

statistics                  0.000017

preparing                   0.000012

FULLTEXT initialization         0.000199

executing                   0.000004

Sorting result                  0.001663

Sending data                    0.000304

end                         0.000005

query end                   0.000004

freeing items                   0.000025

storing result in query cache   0.000007

logging slow query          0.000003

cleaning up                 0.000005

Comment: To profile a query, you do the usual - stick `EXPLAIN` before the `SELECT`, post the output, then stick in `EXPLAIN EXTENDED` - post the output. Also, creating an index on everything doesn't speed things up. Index helps if it's smaller than the data file, which - in your case - it isn't. From what you said, this seems like a design mistake if you have to use FULLTEXT search on each column of your table. There are alternatives to MyISAM and there's definitely better approach to searching the whole table.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Can you be more specific about "better approaches"?

Comment: MyISAM tables do not have a separate index file for the primary key. The table itself is sorted in PK order. Because `LIKE` does not use an index, it accesses the rows in PK order, because that's the way the fields are stored.  The fulltext search traverses the rows in the order that the fulltext index dictates, which is why the result needs to be reordered afterwards.

Comment: OK - what can I do about this? The alternatives to `MyISAM` on offer are `InnoDB`, `MRG_MyISAM`, `BLACKHOLE`, `CSV`, `MEMORY` and `ARCHIVE`.

Comment: @SK9 - InnoDB does not support fulltext indexes, BLACKHOLE doesn't store any data physically (it pipes it all to /dev/null, usage of that engine are for something else), MEMORY keeps it all in RAM - you exceed the ram or shut the computer down it's game over and so on. Real question is what are you trying to achieve, what's the feature you're coding?

Comment: @SK9 I don't know if this is relevant for your problem but, as I understand it, you can apply a sort to a table structure: `ALTER TABLE table1 ORDER BY any_column_name_here`

Comment: @Brendan: I had tried this, with `id`, but it didn't change anything. (Presumably because the table is already sorted by the PK.)

Comment: Is there a memory buffer I can increase some where? e.g. for when sorting?

Comment: Yes, see: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/option-files.html

Comment: btw When I reduce the LIMIT to 20 my performance problem seems to go away. I need to return 30 results here; what does this suggest?

Comment: That your internal buffers are to small to hold the result. Select a different option file from the link I provided.

Answer (score 1):

> 1-Is it possible to presort my table?

No, the table is already presorted by the PK.
The fulltext index forces the rows to be accessed in the order dictated by that index.
For this reason they need to be reordered afterwards.

> 2- what can I do about this?

If you don't mind getting slightly different results, you can change the query to

```
  SELECT * FROM 
    (
    SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE MATCH(myInfo) AGAINST ('stuff') LIMIT 30
    ) as s ORDER BY id
```

To get the next 30 result do `limit 30,30` etc.

You can also speed up the query by not selecting all rows, but only the ones you need. This will limit the amount of data MySQL has to keep in memory and thus the amount of data that has to be moved around while sorting.

```
SELECT id, myinfo FROM mytable ....
```

Comment: Thanks for this. The search results need to be identical to those produced by the `SELECT` statement in my question; an optimized but otherwise equivalent statement would suit me well.

Comment: @SK9, no can do, not without the output from the explain select anyways. Do you **really** need all rows to be displayed?

Comment: @Johan On your first point, I thought you can specify a sort on a table and it doesn't have to be on a PK: `ALTER TABLE table1 ORDER BY non_pk_column`

Comment: I was talking about **pre**sort and a MyISAM table. MyISAM, unlike InnoDB etc does not have a separate index field for the PK, it just presorts the rows in the datafiles in the PK order.

Comment: For any table other than MyISAM this is a great idea though:  `ORDER BY enables you to create the new table with the rows in a specific order. Note that the table does not remain in this order after inserts and deletes. This option is useful primarily when you know that you are mostly to query the rows in a certain order most of the time. By using this option after major changes to the table, you might be able to get higher performance. In some cases, it might make sorting easier for MySQL if the table is in order by the column that you want to order it by later.`

Comment: @Johan: I need the `30` best hits, where the lower the `id` the better the hit. Hence sorting once is to my advantage.

Comment: @SK9, I understand your problem, but without the output from the `explain select` I don't have any info to work with.

Comment: @Johan: I've posted the output of `EXPLAIN SELECT` in an edit - I'm not sure if this helps or not.

Comment: Is there a buffer size I can increase some where? eg. allocate more RAM when sorting?

Comment: btw When I reduce the LIMIT to 20 my performance problem seems to go away. I need to return 30 results here; what does this suggest?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE MATCH(myInfo) AGAINST ('stuff') > 0.25 ORDER BY id LIMIT 30
```

`MATCH(...) AGAINST(...)` returns a match score in the range [0,1] (also called "relevancy"). You can prune intermediate results by filtering for low-relevancy rows (the `> 0.25` in the query above; if you don't specify this in the `WHERE` clause, it's the same as specifying `> 0`).
The 0.25 is arbitrary, try to find a good balance between query time and false negatives.

note: I can't guarantee that you'll get the very same results in all cases, but I really don't see how else it could be done.